# Get rid of code repeating in computed properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a next code in my component:

```
  firstIngredientName: Ember.computed('suggestedIngredients.[]', function() {
    const store = this.get('simpleStore');
    if (this.get('suggestedIngredients.length') > 0) {
      let sugIngredient = this.get('suggestedIngredients').objectAt(0);
      let ingredient = store.find('ingredient', sugIngredient.get('ingredientId'));
      return ingredient.get('name');
    }
  }),
  secondIngredientName: Ember.computed('suggestedIngredients.[]', function() {
    const store = this.get('simpleStore');
    if (this.get('suggestedIngredients.length') > 1) {
      let sugIngredient = this.get('suggestedIngredients').objectAt(1);
      let ingredient = store.find('ingredient', sugIngredient.get('ingredientId'));
      return ingredient.get('name');
    }
  }),
  thirdIngredientName: Ember.computed('suggestedIngredients.[]', function() {
    const store = this.get('simpleStore');
    if (this.get('suggestedIngredients.length') > 2) {
      let sugIngredient = this.get('suggestedIngredients').objectAt(2);
      let ingredient = store.find('ingredient', sugIngredient.get('ingredientId'));
      return ingredient.get('name');
    }
  })
```

As you see each property similar to another, only difference is in a array index.

Here is my template:

```
<span>Some text - {{firstIngredientName}}</span>
<span>Some text - {{secondIngredientName}}</span>
<span>Some text - {{thirdIngredientName}}</span>
```

It really hurts to write such repeating code so I try to find a way to simplify my component. I want get something like next:

```
<span>Some text - {{ingredient 0}}</span>
<span>Some text - {{ingredient 1}}</span>
<span>Some text - {{ingredient 2}}</span>
```

Is it possible to do with emberjs and handlebars?

Comment: How about writing helper and pass `suggestedIngredients` and `index` and that should return the result.

Comment: Then I need to provide access to `store` to this helper. Is it possible and is it good?

Comment: yes that's possible.  `export default Ember.Helper.extend({ store:Ember.inject.service(), compute(params,hash) {  //this.get('store') its possible } });`  i think  injecting store in helper is not good..let us think for other alternative

Comment: I found [this](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_class-based-helpers). So I can assume - creating helper in this case is OK.

Comment: names like `firstIngredient` and `secondIngredient` suggest a code smell.  You should be using an `ingredients` array or collection instead.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, sure... It have a kinda bad smell. That's why I create this topic.

Comment: Well, you accepted an answer that has a `for` loop hardcoded with three ingredients.  What if there are four? or twenty?  Or none?

Comment: In my case I have exactly 3 (mentioned in the question). So, imho, answer with the same condition is pretty normal. But, of course, any number in loop statement can be replaced by `array.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-You can calculate ingredientNames array in single computed propery and access it using each block helper in hbs.

```
ingredientNames: Ember.computed('suggestedIngredients.[]', function() {
        let ingredientNamess = [];
        const store = this.get('simpleStore');
        if (this.get('suggestedIngredients.length') > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                var sugIngredient = this.get('suggestedIngredients').objectAt(i);
                if (Ember.isPresent(sugIngredient)) {
                    var ingredient = store.find('ingredient', sugIngredient.get('ingredientId'));
                    ingredientNamess.push(ingredient.get('name'));
                }
            }
        }
        return ingredientNamess;
    }),
```

-Another approach you can create helper and pass suggestedIngredients and index and that should return the result.

Comment: Didn't think about this problem from that side... Probably, simplest solution. Thanks.

Comment: This is hardcoded to 3 ingredients.  Probably not the best way to do things.

Comment: if OP required to have all `suggestedIngredients` then we should replace `3` with  `this.get('suggestedIngredients.length')`